# Preventing duplicate entries inside of my reducer logic

Tags: reactjs, redux

When a new user is added in the UI, I fire off a NEW_USER action that then updates my redux store.

This works but the problem is whenever a new user is created, there is a websocket connection that sends a realtime update that a new user was created.  This then fires off a NEW_USER action again which inserts the user 2 times.

How can I prevent the user being inserted 2 times in my state.users state property?  Currently you can see I am just appending to the state.list.users collection.  Not sure how to check for the existance in this reduce function.

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'NEW_USER':
      return {
          ...state,
          users: state.lists.reduce((acc, list) => {
                if(list.id === action.list_id) {
                    return [
                       ...acc,
                       {
                         ...list,
                         users: [...list.users, action.user]
                       }
                     ]
                  } else {
                   return [...acc, list]
                  }
              }, []),          
      };
```

Comment: Do you have to dispatch this action twice ? cant you just dispatch one of them?

Comment: *This then fires off a NEW_USER action again which inserts the user 2 times.* -- I don't understand-- why is this happening?  It seems like the place(s) where the action is being dispatched is the more salient code for answering this question...

Comment: @AlexanderNied the action gets fired by the user doing the action.  On the backend, it sends a websocket payload to the UI that then sends another action on the UI (for realtime feature)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Alexander that the root cause of the issue seems to be from wherever the New user action is being dispatched, but to answer your question, I suggest changing your reducer state shape to be more normalized. Creating a map of users by id, and, if iteration order is needed, an array of user ids. And to solve the problem of duplicate entries, you would either filter out the user id from the action and then concatenate the id (remove a duplicate and append the id) or check to see if the is exists, and not concat if it exists (using something like `userIds.some(id => id === action.user.id to check if the id is in the array)`

There is good documentation on normalizing state shape in the redux docs: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.md